# Regarding Contextual Action Bar in webview?

Tags: java, android, webview, contextual-action-bar, long-press

I wanted to hide Contextual action bar in webview long press click. Is there any way to hide or disable it. I tried with below code:

```
webView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

But I don't want to disable long press click. In short I want both long press to be working and CAB to be hide or disable in webview. Is it possible ? any solution welcome. Thanks

Want to hide or disable Contextual Action Bar looks like:
[image]